# Augment maven compilation task

Tags: maven, ant, javac

In Maven, using the compiler plugin, we can do

```
mvn compile
```

and compile the project. What I need is to compile the project AND do some other stuff.

For instance, in ANT I can do this:

```
public class Main extends Javac13 {
    @Override
    public boolean execute() throws BuildException {
        System.out.println("Main::execute");
        attributes.log("Using modern compiler", Project.MSG_VERBOSE);
        Commandline cmd = setupModernJavacCommand();

        try {
            int result = com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(cmd.getArguments());
            return result == 0;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            if (ex instanceof BuildException) {
                throw (BuildException) ex;
            } else {
                throw new BuildException("Error starting modern compiler", ex, location);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setJavac(Javac javac) {
        System.out.println("Main::setJavac " + javac);
        super.setJavac(javac);
    }
}
```

launching it in this way:

```
 ant -Dbuild.compiler=com.moc.Main ...
```

the class above became the compiler and I can do whatever I want with the command line that ANT give to me.
Also, the great thing is that I don't need to touch the build.xml file. I just need to set a system property.

Is there something like this in Maven?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look [system-properties-maven-plugin](https://github.com/carlspring/system-properties-maven-plugin) I knocked-up a while ago. It allows you to define the system properties in your pom.xml. Have a look at the [USAGE](https://github.com/carlspring/system-properties-maven-plugin/blob/master/USAGE) file.

The plugin has two goals -- one for setting the properties (`set`) and one for restoring them back to the original way they were (`reset`).